# PostgreSQL select for attendance between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, time-and-attendance

I'm imlementing attendance table report for date range:

```
Student  01.12 02.12 03.12 04.12 05.12 06.12
STUDENT1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
STUDENT2 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

My table :

```
id_
student_
date_
present_
```

Comment: What is the question ??

Answer (score 1):

I am feeling lucky. So here is my guess at what you might be asking:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      $$SELECT student_, date_, present_
        FROM   tbl
        WHERE  date_ BETWEEN '2015-12-01'::date AND '2015-12-06'::date
        ORDER  BY 1,2$$

     ,$$SELECT unnest('{2015-12-01, 2015-12-02, 2015-12-03
                      , 2015-12-04, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-06}'::date[])$$)
AS ct ("Student" text, "01.12" bool, "02.12" bool, "03.12" bool
                     , "04.12" bool, "05.12" bool, "06.12" bool);
```

Explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)